# x64dbg throwing exception

Tags: debugging, x64dbg, buffer-overflow

I have been working on finding an overflow in WordPad and I was able to run an exception with an undefined behavior (my point of view).

I am using x64dbg (I am not a pro x64dbg) and it shows unexpected HRESULT and almost all registers filled with random values (they don't get filled when a non-corrupted file is loaded).

I am new to x64dbg — how would I go saying this is vulnerable? How do I analyze the exception and the behavior? How do I exploit it?

I have so many questions. Please help. The memory dump is too big, so it is impossible to identify anything. What steps should I follow? Sometimes shows `unexpected HRESULT` on R8 register as well.

[image]

Comment: Please don’t use “x64” as abbreviation of x64dbg, it’s a separate term on its own.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky why do registers get random values even tho this is not an overflow ? How do I analyze the exception

Comment: why do you think these values are random?

Comment: apparently they are not. but why @morsisko

Answer (score 1):

The exception shown in status bar (CPP_EH_EXCEPTION) is a special exception code used to implement C++ exceptions (throw/catch) and usually does not indicate a bug or vulnerability. In most cases it [can be passed to the program](https://github.com/x64dbg/x64dbg/issues/1846) which expects it and will handle it.